ByVal Target As Range not working in auto refreshing /updating workbook
Below mentioned the formula I have tried for an auto updating worksheet but it’s not working.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("B" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("A1").Value
    End If
End Sub

When using this formula only supporting manually entry which means what we are updating in A1 manually it’s working properly when A1 updating automatically from other source A1 column value changing but B value not changing.

Please share the formula in A1 and this worksheet's tab or code (safer) name. Hint: In the Project Explorer (Ctrl+R), the first name is the code name while the second name, the one in parentheses, is the tab name.

A cell containing a formula change triggers only Caltulate event, not Worksheet_Change one...

I am afraid changing the value of a cell containing a formula DOES NOT TRIGGER Worksheet_Change event. Changing a cell value containing a formula triggers Calculate event.
Please, copy the next code in the respective sheet code module:
Option Explicit

Private prevVal

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
  If Me.Range("A1").Value <> prevVal Then
    Range("B" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("A1").Value
    prevVal = Range("A1").Value
  End If
End Sub

First time you test the code, the event will not be triggered only if the formula return is vbNullString (an empty string), which is not so probable, but not impossible. Then, it will work as it should. To overpass this situation you can also use SelectionChange event with a single code line prevVal = Range("A1").Value. But it will consume some of Excel resources. Almost nothing, in fact...
